# Cannot find symbol error when adding android support lib v4 in intellij

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am trying to add android support lib v4 into my project. The problem I am facing is the project is not able to find the support lib. I just downloaded API20 and API 19 plus support files and this doesn't seem to work for me.

The error message I am getting is here:
[image: error message]

My project structure looks like this: 
[image: project structure]

My libs folder is like this:

[image: libs folder]

I tried removing this and adding it again.. I even tried removing the entire sdk and doing it all again but still getting errors in v4 support lib. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Stupid question, did you restart the program? ^^

Comment: yup i restarted the intellij.. even my computer too.. i even tried invalidating the cache and restart option in intellij.. i continue to get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Gradle to add support library to your project.

First delete your manually imported support library from your libs folder and then open build.gradle in your project and add support library v4 dependency:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20'
```

So the block with dependencies looks somehow like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20'
}
```

Don't forget to push "Sync Now" button which appears after every edit of build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I simply moved to Android studio and used support lib with that one though it took a huge time to fix errors of gradle and facebook sdk